# Prove the following equation using Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

$|\cos(nx)-\cos(ny)|\leq n|x-y|\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R},n\geq0$

Comment: Tell us what you tried. (Also, there's a LaTeX tutorial somewhere… maybe someone else will link to it.)

Comment: Hint: first prove this for $n=1$, i.e. show that $|\cos x-\cos y|\leq|x-y|$. Can you prove general case from this special case?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(t)=\cos(nt)$

For some $c\in[x,y]$

$\frac{cos(ny)-cos(nx)}{y-x}=f'(c)=-nsin(nc)\geq-n$

$cos(ny)-cos(nx)\geq-n(y-x)$

$cos(nx)-cos(ny)\leq n(y-x)$

Also, we have

$\frac{cos(ny)-cos(nx)}{y-x}=f'(c)=-nsin(nc)\leq n$

$cos(ny)-cos(nx)\leq n(y-x)$

$n(x-y) \leq cos(nx)-cos(ny)$

Thus, we have:

$n(x-y)\leq cos(nx)-cos(ny)\leq n(y-x)$

$-n(y-x)\leq cos(nx)-cos(ny)\leq n(y-x)$

$|cos(nx)-cos(ny)|\leq n(y-x)=n|x-y|$